# How do you convert tagged YAML objects to JSON objects using a Java library?

Tags: java, json, parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

How do you parse a YAML file containing tagged maps and return nested Java Map<String, Object> objects, where each Java Map contains all entries from the corresponding YAML map, plus an entry where the key is a the String “objectType” and the value is the (String) name of the tag?

In other words, I'd like to parse tagged YAML objects as if they were JSON objects with an entry for the type.

For example, how do you parse this:

```
!ControlGroup
name: myGroup
controls:
- !Button
  name: button1
  size: 10
- !Knob
  name: knob1
  maxValue: 11
  size: 7
```

as if it were this?:

```
objectType: ControlGroup
name: myGroup
controls:
- objectType: Button
  name: button1
  size: 10
- objectType: Knob
  name: knob1
  maxValue: 11
  size: 7
```

I'm already using SnakeYAML in the project I'm working on, so if a solution exists using SnakeYAML, that would be ideal.

Comment: I guess you could inject a custom Parser that processes tags as `objectType: Button` pair, but sadly the SnakeYAML repository has become private for some reason, so I can't check on the specifics. If the indentation is not actually broken like in the code you show, a quick regex replace on the input might be the simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

I've written the [code](https://github.com/klezovics/java-generalized-eigenvalue-problem/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/javabootpad/TestYamlConvert.java) in the form of a unit test, which parses exactly the file you provide using `snakeYml`. Just run it.

```
 @Test
    void testYamlConvert() throws IOException {

        // Step 1: Raad in file
        var in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.yml");
        // System.out.println(in);
        String yml = IOUtils.toString(in,"UTF-8");


        // Step 2: Do in memory replacement to standard form
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("!!(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(yml);

        String ymlWithReplacement = yml;
        while (m.find()) {
            var nameToken = m.group().substring(2);
            // System.out.println("Name token:"+nameToken);
            ymlWithReplacement=ymlWithReplacement.replace("!!"+nameToken, "objectType: "+nameToken);
        }
        // System.out.println(ymlWithReplacement);

        // Step 3: Do the parse ...
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        var myYamlMap = (Map<String,Object>) yaml.load(ymlWithReplacement);

        for(var entry : myYamlMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey() + "Value:" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Here's how the resulting map looks like.

[image]

It should be very easy to get the necessary data from here.
The principle of work is explained in the comments.

**If you need something else for me to be able to claim the bounty, let me know !**

Comment: the solution should be added inline. 10 years from now, the link might be gone, and the solution inaccessible, even though the question might still be relevant

Comment: OK. Will do. Thanks.

Comment: @user10264746 Does this solution work for you ?

Answer (score 2):

what worked was this,

```
!!ControlGroup
name: myGroup
controls:
  - !!Button
    name: button1
    size: 10
  - !!Knob
    name: knob1
    maxValue: 11
    size: 7
```

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        InputStream url = SnakeYml.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.yaml");
        Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(url);
        System.out.println(obj);
```

```
public class ControlGroup {
    String name;
    public ControlGroup() {};

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
....
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem since it does not insert the entry "objectType: ControlGroup" into the resulting Map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        ControlGroup controlGroup = yaml.load(url);
        controlGroup.setObjectType(ControlGroup.class.getName());
        System.out.println(yaml.dumpAsMap(controlGroup));
```

```
public class ControlGroup {
    String objectType = this.getClass().getTypeName();
    String name;
    public ControlGroup() {};

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getObjectType()
    {
        return this.getClass().getTypeName();
    }
    public void setObjectType(String className)
    {
        this.objectType = className;
    }

}

MAP --> 
name: myGroup
objectType: ControlGroup
```

Comment: I appreciate the post, but it doesn't actually solve the problem, since it doesn't create map entries for "Knob" and "Button". More importantly though, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding two methods to every YAML-instantiated class.